# How to find an <a> element that has an href value that contains two given strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Something like this:

```
$("a[href*='string1' && 'string2']")
```

I tried that code without success. I also tried:

```
$("a:contains('string1' && 'string2')")
```

That one just gives me a elements that contain string 2. How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine two `attribute selector` to make it as an `and` operation.

Try,

```
$("a[href*='string1'][href*='string2']")
```